# A program like strtok(), for two delimiters

Tags: c, strtok

I am writing a program to separate comma separated values and date `:`. I am not getting desired output. mark me what I need to change in my program.

Input : `0,0,2,150,123,0,0,1,0,0,0,53,-13,0,102000666,102000665,-,604400000000,-,-,-,-,123456,123,0,0,12:29:2010:7:15:24`

Output : `0 0 2 150 123 0 0 1 0 0 0 53 -13 0 102000666 102000665 - 604400000000 - - - - 123456 123 0 0 12 29 2010 7 15 24`

Expected Output : `0 0 2 150 123 0 0 1 0 0 0 53 -13 0 102000666 102000665 - 604400000000 - - - - 123456 123 0 0 1229201071524`

Please check only date format.

My approach

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char * t = NULL;
    char * line = "0,0,2,150,123,0,0,1,0,0,0,53,-13,0,102000666,102000665,-,604400000000,-,-,-,-,123456,123,0,0,12:29:2010:7:15:24";
    char * s = NULL;
    char temp1[1000] = {0};
    char temp2[1000] = {0};
    for( s=line,t=temp1; s && *s; s++,t++)
    {
        *t = *s;            
    if(*t==',')
    {
            *t=' '; 
        if(*(s+1)==',')
        {
            t++;
        *t='-';
        }
        }
    }
    for( s=temp1,t=temp2; s && *s; s++,t++)
    {
        *t = *s;
        if(*t == ':')
        {
             *t=' ';    
             if(*(s+1)==':')
             {
                 t++;
                 *t='-';
             }
        }
    }
    printf("%s",temp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't you use strtok?

Comment: Actually I do not want to use... I want to implement it. It is just a try to explore C.And my abilities.

Comment: Did you debug it by stepping through your code ?? You also should format your code correctly as this will often show what's wrong.

Comment: @MichaelWalz.. yes and I put my output and expected output also... I am doing something wrong in my logic and could not figure it out so asking for help.

Comment: Maybe change all `','` to `' '` and all `':'` to `''`

Comment: what do  you want exactly? Do you want to get array of seperated words ?

Comment: @AdrianKrupa... Check my code. Do you think I am doing something else?

Comment: @qwr...I am getting my date like this `12 29 2010 7 15 24` and I want it without space like this `1229201071524`. Thats it.

Comment: Why do we even help people like you? We spend so much of our time to help you and you don't even have some gratitude to test the solution or mark it if its working.

Comment: @Abhineet... Do not waste your time. Just downvote my question again. and do your job... I did not ask you to answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    const char *line="0,0,2,150,123,0,0,1,0,0,0,53,-13,0,102000666,102000665,-,604400000000,-,-,-,-,123456,123,0,0,12:29:2010:7:15:24";
    const char *t;
    char temp[1000] = {0};
    char ch, *s = temp;
    for(t=line;ch=*t;++t){
        if(ch == ':')
            continue;
        *s++ = ch == ',' ? ' ' : ch;
    }
    //*s='\0';
    printf("%s",temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not increment variable t in for loop.

Answer (score -1):

Tried and tested :-)
On codepad:: http://codepad.org/Yak3rXO2

```
for( s=temp1,t=temp2; s && *s; s++,t++)
    {
        *t = *s;
        if(*t == ':')
        {
            s++ ;
            *t = *s ; 
        }
    }
```

All you have to do is copy the next element when encountered with a ":". You are trying to replace it with a "Space". So, on each occurrence of ":", increment the `s` to point at next char and then copy that to `temp2`.

Comment: @user2845185: Justify your comment now.